# How to check if one value in textbox is greater than the other, if so show error in span

Tags: javascript, html, angular

[image: These are the 2 textboxes]

I want to check that Per Transacation Limit cannot be greater than Per Day Transaction Limit.

This is what I have so far :

```
<input appNoSpace appTrimOnBlur appNumberOnly maxlength="10" [ngClass]="userUpdateForm.get('perDayTxnLimit').value?'is-invalid':''" class="form-control" type="text" commissionValues (keyup)=" checkTransactionValues(perDayTxnLimit,i,$event)"  (focusout)=" checkTransactionValues(perDayTxnLimit,i,$event)" id="perTxnLimit" formControlName="perTxnLimit">

<span *ngIf="userUpdateForm.controls.perTxnLimit.errors?.required && userUpdateForm.controls.perTxnLimit.touched">
   <small class="form-text error">Per Transacation Limit cannot be greater than Per Day Transaction Limit</small>
</span>
```

Please tell me if I can do it with a function checkTransactionValues() in Javascript or anything else ?

Comment: Have you tried using such a checkTransactionValues() function? What problems did you encounter?

Comment: you can set the type of text box to number and set its max attribute like this `<input appNoSpace appTrimOnBlur appNumberOnly [max]="userUpdateForm.get('perDayTxnLimit').value"  id="perTxnLimit" formControlName="perTxnLimit" type="number">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can put that logic in `checkTransactionValues()` in typescript.

Here is a quick stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-62442698